# Multi-term paste primary without mouse

Tags: multi-term

Have a way to paste the primary selection using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403647/emacs-25-yank-from-x-windows-primary-clipboard-buffer-with-keyboard), but now I want the same functionality with multi-term. Using the function I wrote earlier just causes `"Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *terminal<1>*>"` to print out.

How do I gui-get-primary-selection to work with multi-term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into the code for `term-paste` and came up with the following

```
(defun term-primary-yank ()
 "Paste PRIMARY selection without mouse interaction."
 (interactive)
 (term-send-raw-string (gui-get-primary-selection)))
```

Adding a hook didn't seem to work. Had to set it in term-bind-key-alist under custom-set-variables as in (this could be due to something I have in my own .emacs):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(term-bind-key-alist
   '(("C-M-y" . term-primary-yank))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
              (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-y") 'term-paste)))
```